# Implementing Scientific funtions to HP-35 C++ program

Tags: c++, clion

I am having some problems in trying to Implement some Scientific functions such as, π (**pi**) and the functions **chs** (change the sign of X), 1/x (**recip**), **log** (decimal logarithm), **ln** (natural logarithm), ex (**exp**), √x (**sqrt**), **sin**, **cos**, **tan** (and their inverses **arcsin**, **arccos**, and **arctan**), and xy (**pow**).

The function
names should be accepted in either upper or lower case. Use the functions in the cmath library to do the actual work.
The predefined constant **M_PI** contains the value of pi.

Here is my code below in which I am trying to implement the scientific functions to:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class HPStack
{
    double stack[100]; //stack to store operands
    int top; //defines topmost position of stack
//    const double PI = 3.1415926535897;
    double sin(double x);

public:
    HPStack() //constructor to initialize top
    {
        top = -1; //defines empty stack
    }

    void push(double data) //adds operand to stack
    {
        top++;
        stack[top] = data;
    }

    double pop() //removes operand to stack
    {
        return stack[top--];
    }

    double peek() //gets topmost value of stack
    {
        return stack[top];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HPStack stack;
    string line;

    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        stringstream expression(line);
        string token;
        while (expression >> token) {
            if (isdigit(token[0])) {
                stack.push(atof(token.data()));
            }
            else if (token == "sin")
            {
                double sin(double x);
                stack.push(sin(0));
            }
            else if (token == "-") { // Addition Operation
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(y - x);
            }
            else if (token == "+") { // Subtraction Operation
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(y + x);
            }
            else if (token == "/") { // Multiplication Operation
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(y / x);
            }
            else if (token == "*") { // Division Operation
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                stack.push(y * x);
            }
            else if (token == "M_PI") { // Division Operation
                double pi = M_PI;
                stack.push(M_PI);
            }
            else if (token == "sqrt") { // Division Operation
                double sqrt;
                stack.push(sqrt);
            }
            else if (token == "I") { // Division Operation
                double arcsin;
                stack.push(arcsin);
            }
            else if (token == "arccos") { // Division Operation
                double arccos;
                stack.push(arccos);
            }
            else if (token == "arctan") { // Division Operation
                double arctan;
                stack.push(arctan);
            }
            else if (token == "exp") { // Division Operation
                double exp;
                stack.push(exp);
            }
            else if (token == "pow") { // Division Operation
                double pow;
                stack.push(pow);
            }
            else if (token == "log") { // Division Operation
                double log;
                stack.push(log);
            }

        }
        cout << stack.peek()<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is someone able to give me some help on this? I have started on it as you can see in how I have double PI but I am not having many luck in doing this.

Comment: So what exactly you are struggling with? You can use `tolower` or `toupper` functions (or implement them, ref. to K&R C programming). Otherwise I see you already implemented reversed polish notation as it should be.

Comment: I am struggling in adding in Scientific functions to the program. I am wanting the program to be able to perform calculations such as                                                         
PI 2 / SIN // should be 1 (or very close)                                                                        100 100 * sqrt // should be 100                                                                                     1E-5 LOG CHS // should be 5

Comment: 5 EXP LN // should be 5                                                                                                  3 recip 8 pow // should be 2                                                                                             2 1 arctan cos pow // should be 0.5

Comment: Those are the Scientific calcualtions I am wanting to perform

Comment: Ok, to me it looks like you need some `domain specific language` so `rpn` may work for some cases but in any case an `abstract syntax tree` might be helpful for scientific expressions, or a fast lookup table for expressions.

Comment: Here https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-calculator/tree/master/gcalc is the source code of `gnomecalculator` it's still written in `vala` and I am not familiar with it, but it's still readable and some concepts can be used. In any case you are doing a no small task.

Answer (score 0):

When function names are inputted, you should do the calculation instead of just pushing indeterminate values.

Example:

```
            else if (token == "sqrt") {
                double x = stack.pop();
                stack.push(sqrt(x));
            }
```

Other functions can also be done like this.

To support both uppercase and lowercase characters, it is easy to convert tokens read to lowercase and compare to keywords written in lowercase characters. The conversion can be done like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < token.size(); i++) {
    token[i] = tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(token[i]));
}
```

Add `#include <cctype>` to use `tolower()`.